# Combining two "for" to integrate a progress bar while deleting line in a text file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, progress-bar

I manage to make two python script to work independently. The first one is about looking for a string in a text file and deleting all lines with this string.

```
bad_words = ['first.com','second.org','third.io']

with open('input.txt') as oldfile, open('output.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

The process is quite long because the input as nearly 1 000 000 lines and the bad_words are close to 100 entries.

So I would like to show a progress bar in the terminal while proceeding. I found this, and it is working, incrementing the bar every 1/10 of a second.

```
import time

# Print iterations progress
def printProgressBar (iteration, total, prefix = '', suffix = '', decimals = 1, length = 100, fill = '█', printEnd = "\r"):
    """
    Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
    @params:
        iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
        total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
        prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
        suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
        decimals    - Optional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
        length      - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
        fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
        printEnd    - Optional  : end character (e.g. "\r", "\r\n") (Str)
    """
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix), end = printEnd)
    # Print New Line on Complete
    if iteration == total: 
        print()



# A List of Items
items = list(range(0, 57))
l = len(items)

# Initial call to print 0% progress
printProgressBar(0, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    # Do stuff...
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # Update Progress Bar
    printProgressBar(i + 1, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
```

Instead of a time sleep, I want the progress bar to move forward while each word from bad_words is being processed.

So I came up with that :

```
def printProgressBar (iteration, total, prefix = '', suffix = '', decimals = 1, length = 100, fill = '█', printEnd = "\r"):

    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix), end = printEnd)
    # Print New Line on Complete
    if iteration == total: 
        print()

items = ['first.com','second.org','third.io']
l = len(items)


printProgressBar(0, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
with open('input.txt') as oldfile, open('output.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(items in line for item in items):
            newfile.write(line)
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
    # Update Progress Bar
        printProgressBar(i + 1, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
```

It seems combining the "For If" isn't proper.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "imbrication", but what you have right now does *all* of the writing *first*, and *then* tries to do *all* of the progress bar updates. Except instead of updating for each line of output, it updates for each "bad word". The problem with trying to do this kind of progress bar is that you need to know ahead of time how many iterations there will be. This is why the progress bars you get from your operating system seem so inaccurate - because they often *don't* know, and also the iterations don't all take the same amount of time, so it has to estimate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Karl. By imbrication I mean acting jointly. The number of iterations is defined by "l = len (items)". I also try to set it to be a number "I = 7" (when there was only 7 items in bad_words). This didn't change anything. You got the problem, it tries to do all the writing before doing any update of the progress bar. The output file is created, but stays empty.

Comment: ` The number of iterations is defined by "l = len (items)"` Okay, but now look at what you've chosen as `items`, and how long that is. Does that make sense for what you're expecting to do? `The output file is created, but stays empty.` Well, does the input actually have any "good" lines? Did you try to check that the `newfile.write` call is reached?

Comment: items are strings while in the example there were integers (from 1 to 57).The input file does have 100 000's good lines, I tried with a smaller input file. The result is the same. Is there a way to use the position of the string in the item instead of their value?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you pointed a possible error, I get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.txt' even if there is a file with the same name in the directory. I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

As @KarlKnechtel suggested the way to do it is to count processed lines and not the "bad_words" as they are processed all together at the time.

Adding the progress bar makes the whole script much slower so I will try to make it more efficient.

```
import time

# Print iterations progress
def printProgressBar (iteration, total, prefix = '', suffix = '', decimals = 1, length = 100, fill = '█', printEnd = "\r"):
    """
    Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
    @params:
        iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
        total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
        prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
        suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
        decimals    - Optional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
        length      - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
        fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
        printEnd    - Optional  : end character (e.g. "\r", "\r\n") (Str)
    """
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix), end = printEnd)
    # Print New Line on Complete
    if iteration == total: 
        print()

fname = "A+B_net.txt"
count = 0
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        count += 1
print("Total number of lines is:", count)

l = count

bad_words = ['geovisite.com','cable.dyn.cableonline.com.mx']
printProgressBar(0, l, prefix = 'Avancement:', suffix = 'Completé', length = 50)

with open('A+B_net.txt') as oldfile, open('A+B_sub.txt', 'w') as newfile:
        # for i, line in oldfile:
        for i, line in enumerate(oldfile, 1):  
        # for i, item in enumerate(items):
            if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
                newfile.write(line)
                printProgressBar(i + 1, l, prefix = 'Avancement:', suffix = 'Completé', length = 50)
print("suppression des sous domaines terminé")
```